# how to change text of custom listview button that is added dynamically and how to perform click event of this button

Tags: android

I have a listiview in which rows are like this

ListView

---

[Text1]     [Button1]

### [Text2][Text3]  [Text3]

when i click on button according to status text call go to server.

If suppose status is invite and we click the button  call send  to server according to invite and if status is chat request then button text will be invite and one more button will be shown is this case and if in this case if user click on invite ,then invitation send to visitor.and button text change to join and then if click on join then status text will be again change.how can this possible.

Comment: I may have to start a project myself to tell you what to do.. ask only what you need and be more specific...

Comment: not able to understand what you want.its too messy.please describe step wise using -> so that we are able to understand your problem

Comment: actually i am working on a live chat app.In which i have to show monitoring window that is showing visitors detail.all data we are getting through server.i need whenever any visitor send chat request my list view row will show two button accept and deny and when click on accept the text of that button will change to join and hide the deny button and when click on deny accept text convert to invite.

Comment: @user1008203: ok..got the point!

Comment: then can you tell what exactly i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the adapter for your `ListView`. There is a `getView()` method that you should override.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.rowButton);
    //now that you have it, you can change text whatever

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View button) {
            //do whatever
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I yet not understand your flow of app but i think,you need two or three button depending on some condition of your listitem's buttons clicked.

If so,then simply you will have to design your listitem with 3 buttons only,and when you need 2 of them,just invisible the unwanted one.You can do that in the onClick of the button of your listitem which decides total number of buttons to be displayed.

**EDIT :**

You can follow below code in getView() of your custom adapter class:

lets assume that you have buttons button1,button2,button3:

for status="chat":
button1 text="invite"
button2 text="deny"
button3 is invisible

For otherwise,
button1 text="Join"
button2 text="Invite"
button3 text="Something" and its visible.

```
...getView(...)
{
   ...

   if(status.equals("chat"))
   {
      holder.button1.setText("Accept");
      holder.button2.setText("Deny");
      holder.button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
   }
   else
   {
      holder.button1.setText("Join");
      holder.button2.setText("Invite");
      holder.button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // you can set its visibility for according cases
      holder.button3.setText("Something");
   }
   holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new On....{
      ..onClick(){

           if(status.equals("chat"))
           { // code for invite }
           else
           { //code for join }  
      }
   });
   holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new On....{
      ..onClick(){

           if(status.equals("chat"))
           { // code for deny }
           else
           { //code for invite }  
      }
   });
   holder.button3.setOnClickListener(new On....{
      ..onClick(){

           if(status.equals("chat"))
           { //code for the case when the button is visible } 
      }
   });
   return ..;
}
```